# How to insert data from a select in MYSQL using JSON?

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

The purpose is that I have a succesful INSERT in a table named "ReciboCliente", and it's required and 'userID', but my android apk send only the 'username'. I'm wanting to make a SELECT before INSERT to change the 'username' for 'userID' from the table "Agente". This can be solved into the web service, but I can't do that.

This is the function into the **Web service**

```
public function insertPolizaCliente2(Request $request)
{

    try {


        //fetch table rows from mysql db
        $connection = mysqli_connect("host", "user_name", "pass", "table");

        $sql = "select id from Agente where userID = ".$request->input('agentes')." limit 1";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));


        //create an array
        //$emparray = array();
        if($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $agent[] = $row;
        }

        $agentes = json_decode($agent[]);


        $id = DB::table('ReciboCliente')
            ->insertGetId([
                'noRecibo' => $request->input('noRecibo'),
                'agenteID' => $agentes,  
                'totalPrima' => $request->input('totalPrima'),
                'montoRecibido' => $request->input('montoRecibido'),
                'nombreCliente' => $request->input('nombreCliente'),
                'ced_RNC_Cliente' => $request->input('ced_RNC_Cliente'),
                'telefonoCelularCliente' => $request->input('telefonoCelularCliente'),
                'telefonoOficinaCliente' => $request->input('telefonoOficinaCliente'),
                'direccionCasaCliente' => $request->input('direccionCasaCliente'),
                'direccionOficinaCliente' => $request->input('direccionOficinaCliente'),
                'conceptoRecibido' => $request->input('conceptoRecibido'),
                'formaPago' => $request->input('formaPago'),
                'descripcionVehiculo' => $request->input('descripcionVehiculo'),
                'chasis' => $request->input('chasis'),
                'Placa' => $request->input('Placa'),
                'cilindro' => $request->input('cilindro'), 
                'tonelada' => $request->input('tonelada'),
                'pasajero' => $request->input('pasajero'),
                'grua' => $request->input('grua'),
                'carcelEspecial' => $request->input('carcelEspecial'),
                'Placa' => $request->input('Placa'),
                'cilindro' => $request->input('cilindro'),
                'created_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString(),
                'fechaHasta' => \Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString(),
                'updated_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString(),
            ]);






        if(!empty($id)){
            $posts[] = array('data' => 'inserted');
        } else {
            $posts[] = array('data' => 'not inserted');
        }


        return $this->json_response('200', 'successful', $posts);

    }
    catch (Exception $e){
        return $this->json_response('400', 'error', 'bad request');
    }

}
```

Comment: Is it yur production db credentials???

Comment: It is @devpro. I have already logged in and stolen all of the data. Funny how their avatar is "Anonymous" ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Thanks for your DB credentials. We'll just need your credit card, social security, and passport numbers, as well as your mother's maiden name now...

Comment: You won't take anything importan

Comment: Help me with that :')

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating the right JSON. Change this:

```
if($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $agent[] = $row;
}

$agentes = json_decode($agent[]);
```

to this:

```
if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $agent[] = $row['id'];
}

$agentes = json_decode($agent);
```